# SELECT with MERGE, SQL statement for DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I trying to insert/update user in database and then get ids of changed/updated rows in same statement, but get an error. What's wrong with my statement? Without SELECT statement everything works fine. Thank you.
The SQL statement is:

```
SELECT * FROM FINAL TABLE(
MERGE INTO SMSER.USERS 
   USING (VALUES (cast('55' as VARCHAR(100)), cast('JOHN@TEST.COM' as VARCHAR(100)), cast('JOHN' as VARCHAR(100)), cast('123456' as VARCHAR(100))))
            AS source ( USER_ID, INTRANET, NAME, PHONE )
      ON source.USER_ID = SMSER.USERS.USER_ID

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT ( USER_ID, INTRANET, NAME, PHONE )
      values ('55', 'JOHN@TEST.COM', 'JOHN', '123456'));
```

And error which I receive is:

```
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "SELECT * FROM FINAL TABLE (" was found
following "BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT".  Expected tokens may include:  "<space>".
SQLSTATE=42601
```

Comment: `MERGE` is not (yet) supported as the source for data change tables.

Comment: But here in IBM's article mentioned that it should work http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z9.doc.apsg%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_selectvaluesmerge.htm

Comment: You may want to reference the manual for your actual DB2 version and platform.

Comment: Agreed - what is you version/platform?  Although if you want all the inserted/updated rows, you could _potentially_ run this as three statements (`UPDATE`, `INSERT`, then `SELECT`) - you'd have to lock the table for the duration, though (although there's probably a near-equivalent being performed here anyways).